# WordPress Customise Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site based on Customized cakes. I am stuck with one element where the customer can make his own cake, i.e. can add Base, Toppings, Layers. Its like like PizzaHut or Dominos. where on-click of 1 topping its image will occur, on-click of 1 Base its image will occur and furthermore.
I have done with HTML, JS where on-click I am able to change images of cake, but its all together a different element & this one is different.
I am looking for code suggestion or any links which can be helpful to me. There is a plugin Gravity form but I am looking for other option.
Here A customer can create his Cake by adding Base, Toppings, Layers.

Comment: Hello and wellcome on SO. Please add some code and show us where you struggle. Its hard to tell where the Error may lies

Comment: Hello
Actually i am done with the on-click image change thing, i.e when you click from a drop-down image is changing.
But second part i haven't started yet which is to make layers in an image i.e click on drop-downs will make 1 image to appear and so on to complete the whole cake.
I am unable to start thats why i need suggestion, any code, links or Doc. the site is on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Form Builder is an alternative to gravity
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/